# how can I change the metadata of a video to display a custom duration or a negative duration

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata

I found a broken video that has a negative duration when I open it up in vlc or chrome, but it's metadata seems normal, I also found a webm that has a length of zero but the actual video goes on for about a minute, so is there a way to edit media duration?

Comment: You can remux it.

Comment: How does that change the duration?

Comment: ffmpeg will write the actual duration in the new file.

Comment: I'm aiming to edit the duration to a value that isn't the actual duration

Comment: No sane tool will allow that. You'll need a hex editor. At best, you can get N/A duration by piping Matroska output from ffmpeg.

Comment: do you have any idea on where to look?